# string too large to encode using UTF-8 written instead as 'STRING_TOO_LARGE' at Visual studio 2019 for Xamarin.android project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

When I am building my project at visual studio 2019 at windows or Mac then the following error occurs.
"**string too large to encode using UTF-8 written instead as 'STRING_TOO_LARGE'**. The error is occurs at Visual studio 2019 16.7.7 for windows. But this error is not happening at visual studio 2017. But I need to compile my project to visual studio 2019. [Project properties is given at below screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogpvw.png)

Can anyone please help me. Will be very helpful.

Comment: Try to change the aapt2 option in your android option,look at [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/1111437/view.html)

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I did but after it new error comes "java.exe" exited with code 1" Please see the screenshot https://prnt.sc/vcgrcj

Comment: Did you try to delete the obj and bin file and restart it ?

Comment: I did but same error

Comment: Did you use some large vector drawable?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT dear Can u please guide me that how can I detect large vector drawable ?